# Insert a source file in programlisting with xinclude in docbook

Tags: relative-path, docbook, xinclude

I've the following file tree

```
mainfolder
|-assembly.xml
|
|-chapters
| |-introduction.xml
|
|-source
  |-example01
    |-main.cpp
```

`assembly.xml` is the assembly file of my docbook. It contains a reference to `introduction.xml`.

This is the assembly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly version="5.1"
  xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
  <resources xml:base="chapters/">
    <resource href="introduction.xml" xml:id="introduction" />
  </resources>
  <structure xml:id="main-book">
    <info>
      <description>Book chapters</description>
    </info>
    <output renderas="book"/>
    <module resourceref="introduction"/>
  </structure>
</assembly>
```

`introduction.xml` is docbook `chapter`. I want to insert in it an example including the `main.cpp`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter version="5.1"
  xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xila="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude/local-attributes"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
  xmlns:trans="http://docbook.org/ns/transclusion"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
  <info>
    <title>Introduction</title>
  </info>
  <section>
    <info>
      <title>Chapter title</title>
    </info>
    <para>
    You can see an example:
    </para>
    <example>
    <title>main example</title>
      <programlisting language="c++">
        <xi:include href="./../source/example01/maiin.cpp" parse="text" />
      </programlisting>
    </example>
  </section>
</chapter>
```

Anyway, when I build the book (I'm using personal edition of XMLMind), I don't see anything. In the PDF the example is printed, but instead of the source code inside the `main.cpp` I see

```
<xi:include></xi:include>
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I include the source code from the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced your situation in a different ways and got things working in a both cases.

You didn't mention the exact steps you make to build a book using XMLMind XML Editor (XXE for short), but the following steps certainly worked well.

**None 1**: I've used XXE Professional Edition, but as I know the difference between versions is only in putting random character within text if generating PDF from Personal Edition.

**Note 2**: XXE says that `<description>Book chapters</description>` element is not allowed within you context. Despite that fact, the assembly can be generated successfully.

## 1. Getting things working within XXE

1. Open an assembly file in XXE.
2. Select **Convert** > **Convert document** > **Convert to PDF**.
3. Select a path to save pdf file and press **OK** button.

## 2. Getting things working manually in command line

1. Use your exact files and DIR structure (I included my own `.c`  file sample for my own test).
2. Use XXE assembly processor: http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/assembly.shtml - it has the same codebase that XXE used for working with assemblies from XXE GUI.
3. Get docbook book file from assembly:`assembly-1_0_2_01/bin/assembly -v assembly.xml docbook_book.xml` In my test I've got the `.c` sample file included - that proves that assembly utility works well with XInclude.
4. Get `.pdf` manually: `fop -c <config_file> -xsl <path_to_docbook_ns_stylesheets>/fo/docbook.xsl -xml docbook_book.xml -pdf docbook_book.pdf`

I've got the final result with `.c` sample included in both cases.